# HTML Button, 2 Border Colors

Tags: css, html

This is the html code I have for a button:

```
<input style="border-width: 624px; border-color: rgb(252, 255, 158);">
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

The top left color is the correct color. The bottom right color I have no idea where it is coming from. Any ideas how i could change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to your button:

```
border-style: solid;
```

Or you could combine all of your border styles together like this:

```
border: 624px solid rgb(252, 255, 158);
```

So, the resulting button would look like this:

```
<input style="border: 624px solid rgb(252, 255, 158)" />
```